# Silverlight 4 on Apache Freebsd 8.-8.0

Tags: silverlight, apache, hosting

Whats the latest and greatest for my Apache renegade ISP to host my latest and greatest Silverlight Apps?

Can I setup One Click deployment from Visual Studio (all editions, including Express) to push install it on an Apache Browser? I know this has been seen here before, but I need a definitive answer for my short tempered ISP webmistress. Especially for MS alienware.

Answer (score 1):

From the server's perspective a Silverlight application is just a bunch of static content files.  If you have a means of "One Click" deploying HTML, CSS etc to a web server then you have a means of "One Click" depolying a Silverlight application to a web site.